# Undelete question about population by timezone offset?

Tags: discussion, scope, deleted-questions

I thought ([What percent of earth's population live in a time zone whose UTC offset (in hours) is not a multiple of 1?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374565/what-percent-of-earths-population-live-in-a-time-zone-whose-utc-offset-in-hour)), was a good, on-topic question since it:

- articulates a quite complicated question clearly (although suggestions/improvements very welcome), lays out the research done before asking, presents those findings of the research clearly in the question etc.
- It seems [on topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for GIS, since it concerns geographic segments of a larger area, and their respective populations (seems this is exactly the type of question GIS software is primed to answer)

but it has since been deleted.

Is it possible have it reinstated? My best guess is that it was mistaken a trivial exercise (one comment literally refers to it as a "trivia question")

Also, although the question doesn't specify a particular GIS software, it does contain enough generalisable pseudo code which should be easily written in code to suit any GIS software package (that's the point of pseudocode - that it can easily be interpreted in any language)

Comment: it was deleted automatically by the community bot > https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/roomba [have undeleted the post]

Comment: had to lock the post - the over zealous bot was re-deleting...

Comment: @Mapperz thank you for undeleting, really appreciate it. Do you know if it's possible to make it open for new answers? I eventually found a (very scrappy and poorly referenced) solution (see [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374565/what-percent-of-earths-population-live-in-a-time-zone-whose-utc-offset-in-hour#comment611973_374565)) but there may be others who have better ones

Comment: it should be open as a community wiki now. This is an anomaly hopefully the bot will ignore it for deleting now.

Comment: @Mapperz thanks, greatly appeciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are conflating the terms trivia and trivial. The latter means very easy while the former suggests it’s a question perhaps written for a quiz rather than emanating from your work.

When I read it I thought it might be an assignment question set for a GIS class.

I suspect the question being only posed, albeit with a few hints as to how it might be solved, rather than showing what you had tried to do using GIS software to answer it, is what led to the downvotes that placed it in the path of the Roomba.